# response.data is undefined when downloading files

Tags: java, spring-boot, vue.js

I tried to use spring boot to pass files to vue. The files can be opened, but there's noting in it.
I checked the `res.data`, and it turned out that it is undefined.

Here's the spring boot's code:

The contorller:

```
    @GetMapping("/download/{path}")
    public ResponseEntity<InputStreamResource> downloadFiles(@PathVariable String path, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {
        //fileUtils.getFile(path,response);
        return fileUtils.downloadFile(path);
    }
```

The FileUtils:

```
    public ResponseEntity<InputStreamResource> downloadFile(String path)
            throws IOException {
        String filePath = System.getProperty("user.dir") + "\\files\\" + path;
        FileSystemResource file = new FileSystemResource(filePath);
        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.add("Cache-Control", "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate");
        headers.add("Content-Disposition", String.format("attachment; filename=\"%s\"", file.getFilename()));
        headers.add("Pragma", "no-cache");
        headers.add("Expires", "0");

        return ResponseEntity
                .ok()
                .headers(headers)
                .contentLength(file.contentLength())
                .contentType(MediaType.parseMediaType("application/octet-stream"))
                .body(new InputStreamResource(file.getInputStream()));
    }
```

The Vue's code:

```
    handleDownload(path,fileName){
      request.get('/files/download/'+path+fileName, {responseType: 'blob'}).then(res => {
        console.log(res.data)
        fileDownload(res.data, fileName);
      }).catch((res)=>{
        console.log('download error');
        }
      )
    }
```

I guess the reason there is only'undefined' in the file is that res.data is'undefined'. But I don't understand why res.data is undefined.

Comment: What does `console.log(res)` output?

Comment: Ohhh, the res is the blob! Thank you!

Comment: Happy to help.​

Answer (score 1):

`fileDownload(res, fileName);` works. But I don't know why.